# How to interact with Firebase user after API call?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, retrofit2

I perform API call with Retrofit2 to login user via Firebase Authentication with email and password and after that need to interact somehow with user object, i.e. refresh some data or check if user logged in on next time application starts (I'm getting a correct Json object).

But after API call checking `FirebaseAuth` object `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` gives `null` and have no idea how to save login state inside my app.

```
NetworkService.getInstance().getJsonApi()
    .loginWithEmail(email, password, true)
    .enqueue(new Callback<Transaction.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Transaction.Result> call, Response<Transaction.Result> response) {

            if (response.code() == 200) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");

                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                activity.updateUI(user);

                activity.startService();

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure");
                activity.showToast("Authentication failed.");
                activity.updateUI(null);
            }

            activity.hideProgressBar();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Transaction.Result> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

How to retrieve `FirebaseUser` correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "user shows null".  What specifically are you observing that's different than what you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson FirebaseAuth object mAuth.getCurrentUser() gives 'null' as result.

Comment: Actually I need to retrieve user info - if he is logged in (not null), email, etc

Comment: Why are you expecting the user to be non-null here?  Calling a custom API endpoint will not cause the user to be suddenly signed in.  You're supposed to sign in the user using the API provided by the Firebase Auth SDK.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm actually doing this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password and I really don't understand for now how to check if user is logged in and where user's logged in state saved - at Firebase's server side (so I need to check user state somehow) or at app's side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Firebase Auth REST API to sign in a user, you can't also use the Firebase Auth SDK to manage that sign-in.  You will have to stick to using the REST API for all management.  This means that you'll have to track the ID token that you get from the API, refresh the token every hour before it expires, and maintain your own sense of what it means for the user to be "signed in".

I highly suggest just using the provided SDK, as it will do all of this for you automatically.